# Multiple queries off a single derived table?

Tags: mysql, derived

I have a query that looks like this and it yields a bunch of information

```
mysql> SELECT impacted.incident_id AS id,
    -> impacted.severity_id as sev,
    -> ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(incident.stable_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(incident.start_time)) / 60) AS duration,
    -> ops.department.name AS department,
    -> ops.country.name AS country
    -> FROM incident
    -> LEFT JOIN incident_impactedDepartments AS impacted ON incident.incident_id = impacted.incident_id
    -> LEFT JOIN incident_impacted ON incident.incident_id = incident_impacted.incident_id
    -> LEFT JOIN ops.department ON impacted.dept_id = ops.department.dept_id
    -> LEFT JOIN ops.country ON incident_impacted.entity_id = ops.country.country_id
    -> WHERE incident.status in ('OPEN','STABLE','ALL CLEAR','POST MORTEM COMPLETE')
    -> AND incident.incident_id in (35880,35992,33304);
+-------+------+-----------+-------------------+---------------+
| id    | sev  | duration  | department          | country       |
+-------+------+-----------+-------------------+---------------+
| 33304 |    1 |   29.0000 | Marketing         | NULL          | 
| 33304 |    1 |   29.0000 | Marketing         | GLOBAL        | 
| 33304 |    1 |   29.0000 | Accounting        | NULL          | 
| 33304 |    1 |   29.0000 | Accounting        | GLOBAL        | 
| 35880 |    1 |  109.5833 | Marketing         | Argentina     | 
| 35880 |    1 |  109.5833 | Marketing         | Brazil        | 
| 35880 |    1 |  109.5833 | Marketing         | Canada        | 
| 35880 |    1 |  109.5833 | Marketing         | Chile         | 
| 35880 |    1 |  109.5833 | Marketing         | Mexico        | 
| 35880 |    1 |  109.5833 | Marketing         | Peru          | 
| 35880 |    1 |  109.5833 | Marketing         | United States | 
| 35880 |    1 |  109.5833 | Accounting        | Argentina     | 
| 35880 |    1 |  109.5833 | Accounting        | Brazil        | 
| 35880 |    1 |  109.5833 | Accounting        | Canada        | 
| 35880 |    1 |  109.5833 | Accounting        | Chile         | 
| 35880 |    1 |  109.5833 | Accounting        | Mexico        | 
| 35880 |    1 |  109.5833 | Accounting        | Peru          | 
| 35880 |    1 |  109.5833 | Accounting        | United States | 
| 35880 |    2 |  109.5833 | Finance           | Argentina     | 
| 35880 |    2 |  109.5833 | Finance           | Brazil        | 
| 35880 |    2 |  109.5833 | Finance           | Canada        | 
| 35880 |    2 |  109.5833 | Finance           | Chile         | 
| 35880 |    2 |  109.5833 | Finance           | Mexico        | 
| 35880 |    2 |  109.5833 | Finance           | Peru          | 
| 35880 |    2 |  109.5833 | Finance           | United States | 
| 35992 |    3 | 1295.2667 | Accounting        | Italy         | 
+-------+------+-----------+-------------------+---------------+
```

You can see that incident 35880 impacts 7 countries for Finance. My goal is to gather the following info for each incident.

```
+-------+------+----------+------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| id    | sev  | duration | department                   | country                                                 |
+-------+------+----------+------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 35880 |    1 | 109.5833 | Marketing,Accounting,Finance | Argentina,Brazil,Canada,Chile,Mexico,Peru,United States | 
+-------+------+----------+------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

And I can do so with a query like this:

```
SELECT id, sev, duration, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT department SEPARATOR ',') as department, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT country SEPARATOR ',') as country
FROM
(SELECT impacted.incident_id AS id,
impacted.severity_id as sev,
((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(incident.stable_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(incident.start_time)) / 60) AS duration,
ops.department.name AS department,
ops.country.name AS country
FROM incident
LEFT JOIN incident_impactedDepartments AS impacted ON incident.incident_id = impacted.incident_id
LEFT JOIN incident_impacted ON incident.incident_id = incident_impacted.incident_id
LEFT JOIN ops.department ON impacted.dept_id = ops.department.dept_id
LEFT JOIN ops.country ON incident_impacted.entity_id = ops.country.country_id
WHERE incident.status in ('OPEN','STABLE','ALL CLEAR','POST MORTEM COMPLETE')
AND incident.incident_id in (35880))
AS q1
```

But the severity being pulled is the severity for id 35880 as a whole. See, 35880 impacted multiple departments on a different level and I want to be able to see the severity for the specific department querying versus the master id's severity. However, if I specify the department ID in the query, that breaks things.

```
mysql> SELECT id, sev, duration, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT department SEPARATOR ',') as department, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT country SEPARATOR ',') as country
    -> FROM
    -> (SELECT impacted.incident_id AS id,
    -> impacted.severity_id as sev,
    -> ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(incident.stable_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(incident.start_time)) / 60) AS duration,
    -> ops.department.name AS department,
    -> ops.country.name AS country
    -> FROM incident
    -> LEFT JOIN incident_impactedDepartments AS impacted ON incident.incident_id = impacted.incident_id
    -> LEFT JOIN incident_impacted ON incident.incident_id = incident_impacted.incident_id
    -> LEFT JOIN ops.department ON impacted.dept_id = ops.department.dept_id
    -> LEFT JOIN ops.country ON incident_impacted.entity_id = ops.country.country_id
    -> WHERE incident.status in ('OPEN','STABLE','ALL CLEAR','POST MORTEM COMPLETE')
    -> AND incident.incident_id in (35880)
    -> AND impacted.dept_id = 1473)
    -> AS q1;
+-------+------+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| id    | sev  | duration | department | country                                                 |
+-------+------+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 35880 |    2 | 109.5833 | Finance    | Argentina,Brazil,Canada,Chile,Mexico,Peru,United States | 
+-------+------+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

I no longer get the complete list of impacted departments.

Will this require two separate queries?

Comment: You could do a `max(case dept_id when 1473 then sev end)`, which would get you the severity for the particular department whilst keeping the grouping the same as before.

Comment: Where in the query would I add this statement?

Comment: Which sev? "SELECT id, sev" or "impacted.severity_id as sev"? I tried both and I got "ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'sev' in 'field list"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your query, but I hope either of the below might help:

Query 1:

```
SELECT id, sev, sev1, duration, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT department SEPARATOR ',') as department, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT country SEPARATOR ',') as country
FROM
(SELECT impacted.incident_id AS id, impacted.severity_id as sev, impacted1.severity_id as sev1, ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(incident.stable_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(incident.start_time)) / 60) AS duration, ops.department.name AS department,
ops.country.name AS country
FROM incident
LEFT JOIN incident_impactedDepartments AS impacted ON incident.incident_id = impacted.incident_id
LEFT JOIN incident_impactedDepartments AS impacted1 ON incident.incident_id = impacted1.incident_id AND impacted1.dept_id = 1473
LEFT JOIN incident_impacted ON incident.incident_id = incident_impacted.incident_id
LEFT JOIN ops.department ON impacted.dept_id = ops.department.dept_id
LEFT JOIN ops.country ON incident_impacted.entity_id = ops.country.country_id
WHERE incident.status in ('OPEN','STABLE','ALL CLEAR','POST MORTEM COMPLETE')
AND incident.incident_id in (35880))
AS q1;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT id, sev, duration, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT department SEPARATOR ',') as department, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT country SEPARATOR ',') as country
FROM
(SELECT impacted.incident_id AS id, impacted.severity_id as sev, ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(incident.stable_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(incident.start_time)) / 60) AS duration, ops.department.name AS department,
ops.country.name AS country
FROM incident
LEFT JOIN incident_impactedDepartments AS impacted ON incident.incident_id = impacted.incident_id
LEFT JOIN incident_impacted ON incident.incident_id = incident_impacted.incident_id
LEFT JOIN ops.department ON impacted.dept_id = ops.department.dept_id
LEFT JOIN ops.country ON incident_impacted.entity_id = ops.country.country_id
WHERE incident.status in ('OPEN','STABLE','ALL CLEAR','POST MORTEM COMPLETE')
AND incident.incident_id in (35880))
AS q1
GROUP BY department;
```

I hope that one of the above queries should give results as expected by you.

Comment: #2 is close. It returns 4 rows, each with a department and country as a comma-delimited list of impacted countries. Ideally I will have one row and two comma-delimited lists, one for each countries and departments, then I would query incident_impactedDepartments with the incident id (35880) and department (one of those listed in impacted departments) and get the severity ID of that combination. I don't think that will work, though.\

Comment: Okey, I've made a small correction to #1. Does it seem any closer now? Again I'm sorry I still don't fully understand how you would like the desired output. Based on the dataset you've provided in the question, can you perhaps give a snapshot of how would you like the resultset to look?